# Same query different execution plans

Tags: sql-server, index, database-design, optimization

I am trying to optimize performance for a server and this particular query was causing huge reads from database, in turn causing timeout for queries. This query is generated from EF6 in Asp.Net MVC.

Here is the problematic query:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
[Project1].[C1] AS [C1], 
[Project1].[Date] AS [Date], 
[Project1].[AssetID] AS [AssetID], 
[Project1].[EventData] AS [EventData]
FROM ( SELECT 
    [Extent1].[AssetID] AS [AssetID], 
    [Extent1].[Date] AS [Date], 
    [Extent1].[EventData] AS [EventData], 
    1 AS [C1]
    FROM [dbo].[Alarm] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE ([Extent1].[AssetID] IN (cast(''c6e3142e-5b1f-4a91-90d2-03a504e86ece'' as uniqueidentifier), cast(''4de25e8a-7401-49ae-bd6d-0861d67f0d2f'' as uniqueidentifier), cast(''455e3a5f-1091-4784-9964-0a1a54eaa644'' as uniqueidentifier), cast(''04b46c21-c44f-4b67-b64b-12f2764c0448'' as uniqueidentifier), cast(''a350992b-8548-4bf1-bd22-131c114a5343'' as uniqueidentifier), cast(''98ec1f36-cc54-45d2-a0e3-22aa1b669373'' as uniqueidentifier), cast(''27abcf37-2093-43d5-ae62-2e7b10fe4692'' as uniqueidentifier), cast(''c9f43598-2b9c-47b0-9230-37440e6aea54'' as uniqueidentifier), cast(''c5964caa-5c73-4c0e-bb80-4c1dc7e11039'' as uniqueidentifier), cast(''6ac30678-3876-43c9-b708-61ef19b5ea17'' as uniqueidentifier), cast(''e69d870a-87de-4e3d-b4fc-62c962489a7b'' as uniqueidentifier), cast(''a7c2f407-c605-4491-85fe-66c16fc15586'' as uniqueidentifier), cast(''a38f452e-ee3a-4be7-94ad-99c1474a417f'' as uniqueidentifier), cast(''b0f65616-d5d1-4af9-bffd-9c4b2b7f52e7'' as uniqueidentifier), cast(''3940fed6-9c40-4db6-bdc2-9dc5ef7b49ea'' as uniqueidentifier), cast(''e09f7618-c7d7-414d-b5d7-9ec22b3e9b64'' as uniqueidentifier), cast(''62c91349-d33f-42ed-b16d-a63424acca4a'' as uniqueidentifier), cast(''46812e72-45af-426e-9d72-aafdbcc9c4a7'' as uniqueidentifier), cast(''2a1d2b2a-0471-4f57-adc5-b42a03eb5e01'' as uniqueidentifier), cast(''2797d370-b237-4d2c-bede-b7af67f2b0f4'' as uniqueidentifier), cast(''0c50bb44-133e-4434-b403-c172873564e9'' as uniqueidentifier), cast(''dda75f7a-d366-472e-81b5-c4f3119dd715'' as uniqueidentifier), cast(''cc469264-a706-49c6-961b-d6520437e796'' as uniqueidentifier), cast(''ee2d7ea0-1f94-4cc3-9f64-d8d56374cae5'' as uniqueidentifier), cast(''f7dc6b77-3735-479d-b420-e145d4e3d66f'' as uniqueidentifier), cast(''8a7dbe93-ed1a-49f3-a3d0-e19c6dd4e4ef'' as uniqueidentifier), cast(''b0524a60-f980-4b82-a799-e788a9a4d04b'' as uniqueidentifier), cast(''ceaf8a0b-f410-4f88-9062-e804b76b6e78'' as uniqueidentifier))) AND ([Extent1].[EventCode] = @p__linq__0) AND ([Extent1].[Date] >= @p__linq__1) AND ([Extent1].[Date] <= @p__linq__2) AND (([Extent1].[SiteID] = @p__linq__3) OR (([Extent1].[SiteID] IS NULL) AND (@p__linq__3 IS NULL)))
)  AS [Project1]
ORDER BY [Project1].[Date] DESC',N'@p__linq__0 int,@p__linq__1 datetime2(7),@p__linq__2 datetime2(7),@p__linq__3 uniqueidentifier',@p__linq__0=1799,@p__linq__1='2018-04-22 10:00:00',@p__linq__2='2018-04-23 10:00:00',@p__linq__3='B02A51FE-2248-E611-A64E-782BCB72ACED' 
go
```

So what i did i remove the parameters from query and run it as a single unit like this.

```
 select * from (  SELECT  1 as c1,  [Extent1].[Date] AS [Date], 
    [Extent1].[AssetID] AS [AssetID],         
    [Extent1].[EventData] AS [EventData]  
    FROM [dbo].[Alarm] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE ([Extent1].[AssetID] IN (cast('c6e3142e-5b1f-4a91-90d2-03a504e86ece' as uniqueidentifier), cast('4de25e8a-7401-49ae-bd6d-0861d67f0d2f' as uniqueidentifier), cast('455e3a5f-1091-4784-9964-0a1a54eaa644' as uniqueidentifier), cast('04b46c21-c44f-4b67-b64b-12f2764c0448' as uniqueidentifier), cast('a350992b-8548-4bf1-bd22-131c114a5343' as uniqueidentifier), cast('98ec1f36-cc54-45d2-a0e3-22aa1b669373' as uniqueidentifier), cast('27abcf37-2093-43d5-ae62-2e7b10fe4692' as uniqueidentifier), cast('c9f43598-2b9c-47b0-9230-37440e6aea54' as uniqueidentifier), cast('c5964caa-5c73-4c0e-bb80-4c1dc7e11039' as uniqueidentifier), cast('6ac30678-3876-43c9-b708-61ef19b5ea17' as uniqueidentifier), cast('e69d870a-87de-4e3d-b4fc-62c962489a7b' as uniqueidentifier), cast('a7c2f407-c605-4491-85fe-66c16fc15586' as uniqueidentifier), cast('a38f452e-ee3a-4be7-94ad-99c1474a417f' as uniqueidentifier), cast('b0f65616-d5d1-4af9-bffd-9c4b2b7f52e7' as uniqueidentifier), cast('3940fed6-9c40-4db6-bdc2-9dc5ef7b49ea' as uniqueidentifier), cast('e09f7618-c7d7-414d-b5d7-9ec22b3e9b64' as uniqueidentifier), cast('62c91349-d33f-42ed-b16d-a63424acca4a' as uniqueidentifier), cast('46812e72-45af-426e-9d72-aafdbcc9c4a7' as uniqueidentifier), cast('2a1d2b2a-0471-4f57-adc5-b42a03eb5e01' as uniqueidentifier), cast('2797d370-b237-4d2c-bede-b7af67f2b0f4' as uniqueidentifier), cast('0c50bb44-133e-4434-b403-c172873564e9' as uniqueidentifier), cast('dda75f7a-d366-472e-81b5-c4f3119dd715' as uniqueidentifier), cast('cc469264-a706-49c6-961b-d6520437e796' as uniqueidentifier), cast('ee2d7ea0-1f94-4cc3-9f64-d8d56374cae5' as uniqueidentifier), cast('f7dc6b77-3735-479d-b420-e145d4e3d66f' as uniqueidentifier), cast('8a7dbe93-ed1a-49f3-a3d0-e19c6dd4e4ef' as uniqueidentifier), cast('b0524a60-f980-4b82-a799-e788a9a4d04b' as uniqueidentifier), cast('ceaf8a0b-f410-4f88-9062-e804b76b6e78' as uniqueidentifier))) AND ([Extent1].[EventCode] = 1799) AND ([Extent1].[Date] >= '2018-04-22 10:00:00') AND ([Extent1].[Date] <= '2018-04-23 10:00:00') AND (([Extent1].[SiteID] = 'B02A51FE-2248-E611-A64E-782BCB72ACED') OR (([Extent1].[SiteID] IS NULL) AND ('B02A51FE-2248-E611-A64E-782BCB72ACED' IS NULL))) 
) as proeject1  order by proeject1.Date desc
```

These are the respective IO costs for queries.

```
(3721 row(s) affected)
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Alarm'. Scan count 5, logical reads 69032, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
```

[image: Bad Plan]

Better plan

```
(3721 row(s) affected)
Table 'Alarm'. Scan count 28, logical reads 564, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
```

[image: Good Plan]

[Actual execution plan with good performance](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=BJVDUUsnG)

[Actual execution plan with bad performance](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=BJoyIIjhM)

I have tried:

1. Option recompile
2. DBCC FREEPROCCACHE
3. sp_updatestats
4. Rebuilding corresponding index

But query always picks this plan causing a huge load on server disk.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to use sub-queries?

Comment: @paparazzo it was generated by entity framework

Comment: and have you tried adding the proposed index?

Comment: Are you stuck with entity framework?  Query optimizer can be more efficient with hard values.

Comment: yes i agree, but this query is generated dynamically based on parameter passed in function, first i thought i might a parameter sniffing issue, but seems like its not the case

Comment: Can you upload actual execution plan for good and bad performance?

Comment: @KannanKandasamy yes I have added links for the same

Comment: Nope those links not working...

Comment: @KannanKandasamy I have updated the links

Comment: Is writing TSQL an option?

Comment: @paparazzo Not easily

Comment: What is the type of `Date` column - `datetime` or `datetime2`? Looks like the "bad" query is not choosing the `IX_AlarmEventDate` which seem to be optimal plan for your query.

Comment: @IvanStoev its datetime for date column

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31615760/entity-framework-generates-datetime2-parameters-for-comparing-to-a-date-column, looks similar

Comment: @IvanStoev i tried the query with parameter by changing datetime2 to datetime. and hopefully it has worked in ssms. On the way to implement QueryInterceptor :)

Comment: What is the `CREATE TABLE` including indexes? I see a plan with the 28 seeks despite this mismatch https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2eb4d3eb7cf95f705ec057383453ea87

Comment: @Rohit, add DDL for the `dbo.Alarm` table to your question.

Comment: Ah actually I didn't look closely enough - that plan above does show the problem. The seek is only on the `AssetID, EventCode` part and the date is left as a residual rather than being seeked as when the datatypes are correctly matched.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am missing something but why do you need the sub-query?
OP said from entity framework and even the better query had a sub query.
I wanted to break down the query and it was more than I bargained for.
Worth a try:

```
exec sp_executesql N'
SELECT [Extent1].[AssetID] AS [AssetID], 
       [Extent1].[Date] AS [Date], 
       [Extent1].[EventData] AS [EventData], 
       1 AS [C1]
  FROM [dbo].[Alarm] AS [Extent1]
 WHERE [Extent1].[AssetID] IN (  cast(''c6e3142e-5b1f-4a91-90d2-03a504e86ece'' as uniqueidentifier)
                               , cast(''4de25e8a-7401-49ae-bd6d-0861d67f0d2f'' as uniqueidentifier)
                               , cast(''455e3a5f-1091-4784-9964-0a1a54eaa644'' as uniqueidentifier)
                               , cast(''04b46c21-c44f-4b67-b64b-12f2764c0448'' as uniqueidentifier)
                               , cast(''a350992b-8548-4bf1-bd22-131c114a5343'' as uniqueidentifier)
                               , cast(''98ec1f36-cc54-45d2-a0e3-22aa1b669373'' as uniqueidentifier)
                               , cast(''27abcf37-2093-43d5-ae62-2e7b10fe4692'' as uniqueidentifier)
                               , cast(''c9f43598-2b9c-47b0-9230-37440e6aea54'' as uniqueidentifier)
                               , cast(''c5964caa-5c73-4c0e-bb80-4c1dc7e11039'' as uniqueidentifier)
                               , cast(''6ac30678-3876-43c9-b708-61ef19b5ea17'' as uniqueidentifier)
                               , cast(''e69d870a-87de-4e3d-b4fc-62c962489a7b'' as uniqueidentifier)
                               , cast(''a7c2f407-c605-4491-85fe-66c16fc15586'' as uniqueidentifier)
                               , cast(''a38f452e-ee3a-4be7-94ad-99c1474a417f'' as uniqueidentifier)
                               , cast(''b0f65616-d5d1-4af9-bffd-9c4b2b7f52e7'' as uniqueidentifier)
                               , cast(''3940fed6-9c40-4db6-bdc2-9dc5ef7b49ea'' as uniqueidentifier)
                               , cast(''e09f7618-c7d7-414d-b5d7-9ec22b3e9b64'' as uniqueidentifier)
                               , cast(''62c91349-d33f-42ed-b16d-a63424acca4a'' as uniqueidentifier)
                               , cast(''46812e72-45af-426e-9d72-aafdbcc9c4a7'' as uniqueidentifier)
                               , cast(''2a1d2b2a-0471-4f57-adc5-b42a03eb5e01'' as uniqueidentifier)
                               , cast(''2797d370-b237-4d2c-bede-b7af67f2b0f4'' as uniqueidentifier)
                               , cast(''0c50bb44-133e-4434-b403-c172873564e9'' as uniqueidentifier)
                               , cast(''dda75f7a-d366-472e-81b5-c4f3119dd715'' as uniqueidentifier)
                               , cast(''cc469264-a706-49c6-961b-d6520437e796'' as uniqueidentifier)
                               , cast(''ee2d7ea0-1f94-4cc3-9f64-d8d56374cae5'' as uniqueidentifier)
                               , cast(''f7dc6b77-3735-479d-b420-e145d4e3d66f'' as uniqueidentifier)
                               , cast(''8a7dbe93-ed1a-49f3-a3d0-e19c6dd4e4ef'' as uniqueidentifier)
                               , cast(''b0524a60-f980-4b82-a799-e788a9a4d04b'' as uniqueidentifier)
                               , cast(''ceaf8a0b-f410-4f88-9062-e804b76b6e78'' as uniqueidentifier)
                              )
   AND [Extent1].[EventCode] = @p__linq__0 
   AND [Extent1].[Date] >= @p__linq__1 
   AND [Extent1].[Date] <= @p__linq__2 
   AND (       [Extent1].[SiteID] = @p__linq__3 
         OR  ( [Extent1].[SiteID] IS NULL AND @p__linq__3 IS NULL )
       )
 ORDER BY [Date] DESC', N'@p__linq__0 int, @p__linq__1 datetime2(7), @p__linq__2 datetime2(7), 
          @p__linq__3 uniqueidentifier', @p__linq__0=1799, @p__linq__1='2018-04-22 10:00:00', 
          @p__linq__2='2018-04-23 10:00:00',@p__linq__3='B02A51FE-2248-E611-A64E-782BCB72ACED' 
go
```

try adding the recommended index
create index on EventCode, AssetID, SiteID, [Date]

Comment: this query was generated by entity framework

Comment: please check query with better performance, it too has sub-query, but it work very well